# get objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

assume the following:

```
@interface BOOK : NSObject
{
    @private
    NSString *title;
    NSString *author;
    NSString *ISBN;
}
...
BOOK *booklist = [[[BOOK alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableArray *myarray = [NSMutableArray array];
while (true)
{
    booklist.title = @"title";
    booklist.author = @"author";
    booklist.ISBN = @"1234-1";
    [myarray addObject:booklist];
}
```

my question is how do I retrieve object of BOOK i.e booklist.title, .author, .ISBN at a certain index in myarray.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

with this code? Impossible, because you add the same bookList for the rest of the time (until there is no more memory)

With code without infinite loops you would use

```
NSInteger index = 0;
Book *aBook = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *title = aBook.title;
```

Comment: In the real scenario the while loop is a text stream, so while the text stream is true. I declared myarray in the .h file and the .m file I have some functions that call myarray. after assigning the values, I called [myarray ObjectAtIndex:index] but I get a "SIGABRT" in xcode.

Comment: if you don't post the real code I can't help. If you get an error or exception you should post the exact code that caused that exception.

Comment: this is the exact lineBook *aBook = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];

Comment: this is the exact line Book *aBook = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
actually I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. the code is quite much.

Comment: no error when I call myarray from the same function I populate it but when I call from another function to get the value at a certain index I get the error above.

Comment: how can you access myArray from another method if it's declared local? You see, you have to post the real code. --- EXC_BAD_ACCESS can be caused by a release that happens to early. But I don't know how your actual code looks like, so I can't tell you if you should replace `[NSMUtableArray array]` with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

Comment: Please see the code at http://onlinestarter.biz/code.zip line 203 is where I call it from and I populate it at line 357 both of the .m file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: calling [myArray retain] before exiting the method that populate the array makes it accessible from other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Xcode 4.5 (and Clang 3.3), you may use [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
Book *firstBookInArray = myArray[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not help at all, but I remember having trouble when not casting while pulling objects out of arrays...

```
Book *aBook = (Book *)[myArray objectAtIndex: index];
```

It may help, may not...and I know this post is old, but maybe it'll help someone..

.scott

Comment: Yes. This has been a must do in the past.  I believe it returns (id) and casting it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have this extends if you want

Create file **extends.h** add this code and **#import "extends.h"** in your project :

```
/*______________________________ Extends NSMutableArray ______________________________*/
/**
 * Extend NSMutableArray
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@interface NSMutableArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index;
@end
/**
 * Extend NSMutableArray Method
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@implementation NSMutableArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index {
    NSInteger anIndex = index;
    NSObject *object = [self objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OK found ");
        return object;
    }

}
@end
/*______________________________ Extends NSArray ______________________________*/
/**
 * Extend NSArray
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@interface NSArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index;
@end
/**
 * Extend NSArray Method
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@implementation NSArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index {
    NSInteger anIndex = index;
    NSObject *object = [self objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OK found ");
        return object;
    }

}
@end
```

**USE :**

```
NSObject object = [self.arrayItem getAt:0];
NSObject object2 = [self.arrayItem getAt:50];
```